# UPDATE working fine but $mysqli->affected_rows says no rows updated

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is the query:

```
$query = "UPDATE user_data SET user_privil = ? WHERE e_mail = ? AND user_name = ?";  
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){  
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $user_privil, $e_mail, $user_name);  
$stmt->execute();
```

The user_privil cell updatesupdates just fine. However `$stmt->affected_rows` does not equal 1.

I can use `var_dump($query)` and it outputs "donestring(71)" followed by the `$query` above.

I can use `var_dump($mysqli)` and it says: `["affected_rows"]=>int(0)` in the array output. The `var_dump($mysqli)` array does not indicate any errors.

I can use `var_dump($stmt)` and the array says the same thing as `var_dump($mysqli)` above: `["affected_rows"]=>int(0)`. The output array does not show any errors.

I can look in the phpMyAdmin and see that the user_privil table cell HAS been updated.

I use json_encode to encode an array before inserting the data into the user_privil cell.

I can use the "if" conditional suggested by user Michael at this link:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php
Michael's suggestion returns "true" if the row updates. However, it also returns "true" is the row is not updated.

I am running:
PHP version 5.6.30
MySQL version 5.6.33
Apache 2.4.25

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that your issue: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php#60134

Comment: If you run an update query that in fact does not update anything. If the values you are sending with the update query is the same as it's already are in the table then it wont be any affected rows. Are you sure you are actually changing data?

Comment: It _is_ updating. A user registers for my website. It automatically sends a link to the e-mail address for the new registrant.Before updating `{"eins":0,"zwei":0,"drei":0,"vier":0,"funf":"file_get_contents((__DIR__).\"\/html\/pay_pal_link.html\")","sechs":0}` **after** updating `{"eins":0,"zwei":0,"drei":0,"vier":0,"funf":"file_get_contents((__DIR__).\"\/html\/pay_pal_link.html\")","sechs":1}` "seches" (word six in German) is updated to 1.

Comment: I tried `$stmt->store_result()` yesterday. `$stmt->affected_rows` still false. I just tried it again. Same outcome. [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php#60134](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php#60134)

Comment: Where is it you're putting the `$stmt->affected_rows`? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php says that it will get the affected rows of the _last executed statement_ - are you sure you're not performing another query between the one in your question and the call to `affected_rows`?

Comment: Starts with: `$query = "UPDATE...` next line `if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...` next line: `$stmt->bind_param('sss'...` next line: `$stmt->execute()` next line: `$stmt->store_result` next line: `if ($stmt->affected_rows){...` It's got to be something simple. This same question has been asked before on this forum. But I can't get any of the answers to work.

Comment: Are you able to update your question with more code for us to take a look at? So from your `$query = ...` all the way down to your `if ($stmt->affected_rows){...` so we can see what's going on. Also, I'd suggest removing `$stmt->store_result` as that is only useful when the query returns a result set, which an `UPDATE` query won't do. (See the return value section [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php).)

Comment: @crazyloonybin Thanks for touching bases. I checked my server logs. The server is hitting some of the pages twice. The first hit is when the mysqli query updates the record. At the second hit there is no update. That explains why `affected_rows` is showing false. I use the Apache mod_rewrite to re-write the URLs. I am studying on that now. Thanks again.

Comment: @Harvey not a problem! Yes having the page hit for a second time will likely be causing the issue that JustOnUnderMillions mentioned above, where, because the row hasn't had any values changed the second time the page gets hit, the row isn't being seen as having been updated. Feel free to come back if you come across something else you get stuck with!